# I need to sort a multi-table query, that is grouped, can it be done without doing a subquery?

Tags: php, mysql

here's my php MySQL syntax

```
$query_cruises = "SELECT * FROM cruises, fares WHERE cruises.id = fares.cruise_id AND cruises.offer = 'Y' GROUP BY cruises.code ORDER BY fares.offer ASC";
```

What's happening is the recordset doesn't sort by fares.offer. It lists one record (correct) but not in the price order (should show the lowest value from fares.offer)

So what I have is two tables, cruises and fares.

The cruises table has all the cruise info, the fares table has a list of prices for each cabin on that cruise, related to each other by cruises.id and fares.cruise_id

So I join the tables, no problem, but I want to one record which contains the cruise title, description and the lowest fare from the fares table.

The recordset would read something like

Cruise round the UK, from only £329

Hope this makes sense on what I'm trying to acheive !

Ta

Rich :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT  cruises.*,
        MIN(fares.offer) AS min_fare
FROM    cruises
JOIN    fares
ON      fares.cruise_id = cruises.id
WHERE   cruises.offer = 'Y'
GROUP BY
        cruises.code
ORDER BY
        min_fare
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT c.code, min(f.offer)
FROM cruises c , fares f 
WHERE c.id = f.cruise_id 
AND c.offer = 'Y' 
GROUP BY c.code
```